# What is the capacity of the logsBloom?

Tags: logs

The logs bloom filter in the block header has a size of 2048 bits. How many messages will it accommodate before the false positive rate is too high for it to be useful anymore? If a formula could be provided that would be excellent.

Comment: This is a great resource for bloom filters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter. There's a formula there. Sorry, I don't have time to craft a good answer, but if you find on in the link, you can answer your own question and get some credit.

Comment: I wanted some clarification on Ethereum's case because it seems to work out to about 50% false positive rate at ~1000 messages and I couldn't find anything written about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Thomas already suggested, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter is a good resource for this.

As far as I understand, it works like this (correct please if wrong):

The estimate formula for false positive is `(1-e^(-k*n/m))^k`

Ethereum yellow paper says:

> M3:2048 is a specialised Bloom filter that sets three bits out of 2048, given an arbitrary byte sequence.

Hence k=3, m=2048

For this we get the following false positive estimates (n = number of contract addresses and log topics contained in the bloom filter):

```
n =  100 ->  ~0,25%
n =  200 ->  ~1,64%
n =  430 -> ~10,20%
n = 1080 -> ~50,14%
n = 4000 -> ~99,15%
```